# ¿Como llenar a traves de Jquery o JS un arreglo proveniente de JSON para gráficos charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Para ahorrarme el pasar varias variables a la vista, pense en poder hacer un arreglo que me trae años y el total por cada pagina en que se accedieron, el tema que no logro imprimir tanto el año como los datos en el grafico.

Asi lo llene desde el controlador, el cual si me trae los datos como pueden ver más adelante, o la otra seria separar por cada pagina crear arreglo?

```
for ($i=$currentYear; $i > $currentYear - 5; $i--) { 
            $years[] = $i;
            $dataPort = isset($_portal[$i]) ? $_portal[$i] : 0;
            $dataToc = isset($_toc[$i]) ? $_toc[$i] : 0;
            $dataEnlace = isset($_enlace[$i]) ? $_enlace[$i] : 0;
            $dataWeb = isset($_web[$i]) ? $_web[$i] : 0;
            
            $accessDoor[] =[
                'year' => $i,
                'portal' => $dataPort,
                'enlace' => $dataEnlace,
                'toctoc' => $dataEnlace,
                'webbi' => $dataWeb,
            ];
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi es como se ve en la consola los datos que traigo, si pongo access.year me aparece en la columna **object object**, y si lleno datos access.portal desaparece el grafico.

```js
//const access = <?php echo json_encode($accessDoor)?>;
//    console.log(access);
    var optionsGeneral = {
        series: [{
            name: 'Portal Inmobiliario',
            data: [44, 55, 41, 37, 22, 43, 21]
        }, {
            name: 'TOC TOC',
            data: [53, 32, 33, 52, 13, 43, 32]
        }, {
            name: 'Enlace Inmobiliario',
            data: [12, 17, 11, 9, 15, 11, 20]
        }, {
            name: 'Web B-I',
            data: [25, 12, 19, 32, 25, 24, 10]
        }],
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            height: 350,
            stacked: true,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                horizontal: true,
            },
        },
        stroke: {
            width: 1,
            colors: ['#fff']
        },
        /*title: {
            text: 'Fiction Books Sales'
        },*/
        xaxis: {
           categories: [2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020],
            labels: {
                formatter: function (val) {
                   return val + "K"
                }
            }
        },
        yaxis: {
            title: {
                text: undefined
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            y: {
                formatter: function (val) {
                    return val + "K"
                }
            }
        },
        fill: {
            opacity: 1
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
            horizontalAlign: 'left',
            offsetX: 40
        }
    };
    
    var chartGeneral = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chartGeneral"), optionsGeneral);
    chartGeneral.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<div id="chartGeneral"></div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás armando las series con el formato adecuado, porque en cada elemento estás agregando año, portal, toc, enlace y web, sin embargo, debes crearlos en este formato:

```
[
   { name: 'Nombre o etiqueta del elemento', data: [val1, val2, valX]}
]
```

Probablemente se pueda ahorrar un paso, pero, para tratar de hacerlo un poco más claro:

- Crear un arreglo con clave => Nombre de la etiqueta a mostrar en gráfico
- Crear otro arreglo con clave => Valores por año
- Recorres los años con el ciclo como lo tienes ahora
- Agregas cada año al arreglo para mostrar después como categoría
- Agregas cada valor a la clave que corresponda
- Finalmente, haces otro ciclo para armar la salida con `name` y `data` para cada elemento

```
$_portal = [2015 => 44, 2016 => 55, 2017 => 41, 2018 => 37, 2019 => 22, 2020 => 43];
$_toc = [2015 => 53, 2016 => 32, 2017 => 33, 2018 => 52, 2019 => 13, 2020 => 43];
$_enlace = [2015 => 12, 2016 => 17, 2017 => 11, 2018 => 9, 2019 => 15, 2020 => 11];
$_web = [2015 => 25, 2016 => 12, 2017 => 19, 2018 => 32, 2019 => 25, 2020 => 24];

$currentYear = 2020;
// Arreglo para clave y nombre de elementos
$nombres = [
    'portal' => 'Portal Inmobiliario',
    'toc' => 'TOC TOC',
    'enlace' => 'Enlace Inmobiliario',
    'web' => 'WEB B-I'
];
// Arreglo para almacenar resultados por clave
$data = [
    'portal' => [],
    'toc' => [],
    'enlace' => [],
    'web' => []
];
// Arreglo para años, este ya lo tenías bien
$years = [];
for($i = $currentYear; $i >= $currentYear - 5; $i --) {
    $years[] = $i;
    // Agregar cada valor en la clave que corresponda
    $data['portal'][] = (isset($_portal[$i])) ? $_portal[$i] : 0;
    $data['toc'][] = (isset($_toc[$i])) ? $_toc[$i] : 0;
    $data['enlace'][] = (isset($_enlace[$i])) ? $_enlace[$i] : 0;
    $data['web'][] = (isset($_web[$i])) ? $_web[$i] : 0;
}

// Crear arreglo para salida final
$accessDoor = [];
foreach($nombres as $key => $nombre) {
    // Agregar cada elemento con sus datos en el formato adecuado
    $accessDoor[] = [
        'name' => $nombre,
        'data' => $data[$key]
    ];
}

// Crear variables para Javascript:
echo 'let series = ' . json_encode($accessDoor) . ";\n";
echo 'let categories = ' . json_encode($years) . ";\n";
```

El resultado de ambas variables aparece en las primeras líneas del siguiente *fragmento de código* y solo es necesario asignar en las opciones correspondientes:

```js
// Este es el resultado de las dos últimas líneas del código PHP
let series = [
    {"name":"Portal Inmobiliario","data":[43,22,37,41,55,44]},
    {"name":"TOC TOC","data":[43,13,52,33,32,53]},
    {"name":"Enlace Inmobiliario","data":[11,15,9,11,17,12]},
    {"name":"WEB B-I","data":[24,25,32,19,12,25]}
];
let categories = [2020,2019,2018,2017,2016,2015]; 

var optionsGeneral = {
        // Se agregan los datos de PHP definidos arriba
        series: series,
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            height: 350,
            stacked: true,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                horizontal: true,
            },
        },
        stroke: {
            width: 1,
            colors: ['#fff']
        },
        xaxis: {
           // Se agregan los datos de PHP para categorías
           categories: categories,
            labels: {
                formatter: function (val) {
                   return val + "K"
                }
            }
        },
        yaxis: {
            title: {
                text: undefined
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            y: {
                formatter: function (val) {
                    return val + "K"
                }
            }
        },
        fill: {
            opacity: 1
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
            horizontalAlign: 'left',
            offsetX: 40
        }
    };
    
    var chartGeneral = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chartGeneral"), optionsGeneral);
    chartGeneral.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<div id="chartGeneral"></div>
```